# How to pass query parameters with a routerLink

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to pass a query parameter `prop=xxx`.

This didn't work

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/somepath', {queryParams: {prop: 'xxx'}}]">
  Somewhere
</a>
```

Comment: The syntax that you want to use is for matrix parameters and this is the form `<a [routerLink]="['/somepath', { foo: 'foo' }]">Somewhere</a>`, this gives you a matrix url parameters (semicolon ; instead of ? and & separators) and you can access this by ActivatedRoute.params instead activatedRoute.queryParams

More information here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688084/how-get-query-params-from-url-in-angular2

and here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048121/url-matrix-parameters-vs-request-parameters

Comment: Query parameters and matrix parameters are the same. The only difference is when they are added to the root segment, they are serialized as query parameters, when they are added to a child segment, they are serialized as matrix parameters.

Comment: Have some more differences
check this http://web.archive.org/web/20130126100355/http://brettdargan.com/blog/2009/01/16/query-vs-matrix-params
Also you can check the link parameter syntax in the angular doc here
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#link-parameters-array

Comment: queryParams can be added using a separate input field in the routerLink directive. You can check for more details on how to use routerLink in my guide: https://indepth.dev/tutorials/angular/indepth-guide-to-passing-parameters-via-routing

Answer (score 641, accepted):

**`queryParams`**

`queryParams` is another input of `routerLink` where they can be passed like

```ts
<a [routerLink]="['../']" [queryParams]="{prop: 'xxx'}">Somewhere</a>
```

**`fragment`**

```ts
<a [routerLink]="['../']" [queryParams]="{prop: 'xxx'}" [fragment]="yyy">Somewhere</a>
```

**`routerLinkActiveOptions`**

To also get routes active class set on parent routes:

```ts
[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: false }"
```

To pass query parameters to `this.router.navigate(...)` use

```ts
let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
  queryParams: { 'session_id': sessionId },
  fragment: 'anchor'
};

// Navigate to the login page with extras
this.router.navigate(['/login'], navigationExtras);
```

See also https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments

Comment: How would this work programmatically?
I tried with this.router.navigate( ['/resetPassword', { queryParams: { username: loginName }}]); But the result was: http://localhost:8100/resetPassword;queryParams=%5Bobject%20Object%5D

Comment: I updated my answer. See also the link I added. It shows a full example.

Comment: Couple notes: rickul's code should be `[ '/resetPassword' ], { queryParams: { username: loginName }})` where the `]` comes before the extras. Also don't forget that query params are case sensitive.

Comment: Don't forget to subscribe to the queryParams on the target: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39146396/2726844

Comment: Or if you're using routes, `runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'` will reload the route  https://medium.com/engineering-on-the-incline/reloading-current-route-on-click-angular-5-1a1bfc740ab2

Comment: Don't forget to use `routerLink` instead `href` on the link. Command `<a href="..." [queryParams]="...">` will fail with `Can't bind to 'queryParams' since it isn't a known property of 'a'`.

Comment: @rickul, unfortunately angular does not (yet?) provide any way to support objects in the queryParams's value. I opened [a feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/47307) to raise this limitation. Please consider voting the ticket  so that they move it to their consideration list.

Answer (score 57):

```
<a [routerLink]="['../']" [queryParams]="{name: 'ferret'}" [fragment]="nose">Ferret Nose</a>
```

```
foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
\_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
 |           |            |            |        |
scheme    authority      path        query   fragment
```

For more info -
https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments

Answer (score 15):

For those who want to pass dynamic querystring params, this worked for me:

assume you have component model

```
x = {name:'xyz'}
```

html:

```
<a [routerLink]="['../']" [queryParams]="{prop: x.name}">Somewhere</a>
```

this will generate link:

```
../?prop=xyz
```

Comment: What if we have a value in component

Answer (score 7):

You can check out this as well.

```
 <router-link
 
:to="{name:'router-name', params: { id:param1}, query:{link:query1}}"

>
 link name

 </router-link
>
```