# How to pass a parameter to routerLink that is somewhere inside the URL?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router3

I know I can pass a parameter to `routerLink` for routes such as

```
/user/:id
```

by writing

```
[routerLink]="['/user', user.id]"
```

but what about routes such as this one:

```
/user/:id/details
```

Is there a way to set this parameter or should I consider a different URL scheme?

Comment: The array of URL fragments consists of all parts of the route you want to redirect to.  We have to keep the same fragments order as in the route definition. More details about this and how to redirect using Router or RouterLink directive here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880876/how-to-pass-query-parameters-with-a-routerlink#comment130056069_37880876

Answer (score 455, accepted):

In your particular example you'd do the following `routerLink`:

```
[routerLink]="['user', user.id, 'details']"
```

To do so in a controller, you can inject `Router` and use:

```
router.navigate(['user', user.id, 'details']);
```

More info in the Angular docs [Link Parameters Array](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-link-parameters-array) section of [Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Comment: can you provide any link where I can find more information about this..

Comment: @CleanCrispCode You can read more about it in the Angular docs at router guide: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#link-parameters-array

Comment: What about the `<button mat-button routerLink="...">View user</button>` syntax ?

Answer (score 67):

Maybe it is really late answer but if you want to navigate another page with param you can,

```
[routerLink]="['/user', user.id, 'details']"
```

also you shouldn't forget about routing config like ,

```
 [path: 'user/:id/details', component:userComponent, pathMatch: 'full']
```

Answer (score 23):

First configure in table:

```
const routes: Routes = [  
{
  path: 'class/:id/enrollment/:guid',
  component: ClassEnrollmentComponent
 }
];
```

now in type script code:

```
this.router.navigate([`class/${classId}/enrollment/${4545455}`]);
```

receive params in another component

```
 this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
  let id = params['id'];
  let guid = params['guid'];

  console.log(`${id},${guid}`);
  });
```

Answer (score 12):

It's very simple

```
<a routerLink="/user/{{id}}/details"></a>
```

Comment: Works perfect, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Torben You are welcome

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple ways of achieving this.

- Through [routerLink] directive
- The navigate(Array) method of the Router class
- The navigateByUrl(string) method which takes a string and returns a promise

The routerLink attribute requires you to import the routingModule into the feature module  in case you lazy loaded the feature module or just import the app-routing-module if it is not automatically added to the AppModule imports array.

- RouterLink

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user', user.id]">John Doe</a>
<a routerLink="urlString">John Doe</a> // urlString is computed in your component
```

- Navigate

```
// Inject Router into your component
// Inject ActivatedRoute into your component. This will allow the route to be done related to the current url
this._router.navigate(['user',user.id], {relativeTo: this._activatedRoute})
```

- NavigateByUrl

```
this._router.navigateByUrl(urlString).then((bool) => {}).catch()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params['type'])
  });  }
```

This works for me!

Comment: in the case you would use this.activatedRoute.parmas.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params['type'])
  });  }
 so params instead of query paramas to get the parameter from the url

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You're not using routerLink to create a link here. You're just parsing queryParams if there are any ...

Answer (score 1):

`app-routing.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent },
  { path: 'product/:id', component: ProductDetailsComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/products', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

In controller you can navigate like this,

```
this.router.navigate(['/products', productId]);
```

It will land you to path like this: http://localhost:4200/products/product-id

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38062909/3411787)

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

in the case you would use

```
`this.activatedRoute.parmas.subscribe(params => { console.log(params['type']) }); }`
```

so params instead of queryparamas to get the parameter from the url –

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic values to generate the link. For a dynamic link, pass an array of path segments, followed by the params for each segment.
For example, `['/team', teamId, 'user', userName, {details: true}]` generates a link to /team/11/user/bob;details=true.