# Angular 4 - Adding router param before url

Tags: angular, angular-router

Just wondering whether there is a way to create a angular route with parameter before of in-between a url,

```
{path: ':param/test/list'} or {path: 'web/:param/list'}
```

and reference it in routerLink directive,

```
[routerLink]="['test/list', paramValue]"
```

Thee parameter value is always getting appended to the end of the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
path: { ':parameter/test/list' }
[routerLink]="[paramValue + 'test/list']"
```

or

```
path: { 'test/:parameter/list' }
[routerLink]="['test/' + paramValue + '/list']"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put parameter segment in same position to route. Something similar:

```
path: { ':parameter/test/list' }
[routerLink]="[paramValeu, 'test', 'list']"
```

Edit:

Separate segments in Route link.

Comment: Thanks Martin. When I do this the '/' in the URL 'test/list' gets replaced with '%2F' which is the encoding reference for the slash character.
Like - 'paramValue/test%2Flist

Comment: Well maybe you need to change route link: [routerLink]="[paramValeu, 'test', 'list']. Because route link use the route segments separate.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help :) [How to pass a parameter to routerLink that is somewhere inside the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062702/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-routerlink-that-is-somewhere-inside-the-url)

Always better to use router instead of [href]

Good luck