# Angular Router does not resolve required parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I am creating an application with Angular and the Angular router. For navigating to one of the sub pages I need a required parameter in my url. How this should be done can be found in the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action). But somehow this method is not working in my project.

**Versions:**

- @angular/core: `7.2.6`
- @angular/router: `7.2.6`

---

**What I am trying to accomplish**

I have a product list on one page and detail information on the second page. 
The routes of the pages are as follows:

- Main page:   `/product-list`
- Detail page: `/product-list/:id/info`

The detail page is relative to the main page.

I've tried navigating to the page via:

```
this.router.navigate(
  [':id/info', item.id], 
  { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute }
)
```

But this results in an error from the Angular router: `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ':id/info/03-BR'`.

I reproduced this behavior in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gqjkzg).

---

**Manually changing the :id**

I can navigate to the url if I replace the `:id` myself, so using `['01-CE/info']`as a configuration redirects to the url. So it looks like the router doesn't work as it is described in the docs or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Check this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062702/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-routerlink-that-is-somewhere-inside-the-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is not a replacement, it is a join.

Try

```
this.router.navigate(
  [item.id, 'info'], 
  { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute }
)
```

Comment: You are right, append does work. Replacing the param would be better in my opinion... But anyway, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply Change  `[':id/info', item.id]`,  with `['item.id', 'info']`