# <a> element href stops working with (click) on it

Tags: angular, onclick, href

My navbar.html:

```
 <li>
 <a (click)="Close= !Close" href="/page1" >This Page</a>
 </li>
 <li>
 <a (click)="Close= !Close" href="/page2" >Another Page</a>
 </li>
```

app.html :

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I have a menu that opens and close if the Close variable is true or false with the help of css using transitions.
Right now if i click on an element of the menu, my navbar blinks back to close state without animation and reload the content of the page. The solution i found was to add the `(click)="Close= !Close"` to each element of the menu, so they could control the open/close animation too.

When i added `(click)="Close= !Close"` to each element attribute the href stoped redirecting, I removed `(click)="Close= !Close"` and confirmed that it was causing my href to do its work.

This works:

```
 <li>
 <a href="/page1" >This Page</a>
 </li>
```

This dont:

```
 <li>
 <a (click)="Close= !Close" href="/page1" >This Page</a>
 </li>
 <li>
```

Is it normal? Is there any workaround? I need to use another type of href on Angular?

<------------- UPDATE 1--------------->

When i hover over the element it shows correctly the link where this element should take me, event with `(click)="Close= !Close"` in the attributes

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `routerLink`

```
<a (click)="Close= !Close" [routerLink]="['/page1']" >This Page</a>
```

Comment: Like this worked `routerLink="/page1"` why would i need the brackets?

Comment: And thanks very much, wasn't expecting to be so easy

Comment: `[routerLink]` is angular way of doing it. You can pass variable to it. `[routerLink]=navigateUrl`. In your case it is not required

Comment: For more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370760/difference-between-routerlink-and-routerlink