# What is the benefit of using [routerLink] instead routerLink with simple urls

Tags: angular, binding, routes

With simple urls the folowing routes the following examples:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/foo/bar']"></a>
```

and

```
<a routerLink="/foo/bar"></a>
```

will make no difference. But even in the [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description) we find examples like:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user/bob']" preserveQueryParams preserveFragment>
  link to user component
</a>
```

So what is te advantage of using the attribute binding instead simple binding with routerLink directive in angular?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370760/difference-between-routerlink-and-routerlink)

Comment: @Freddy I've seen that question before but not answer what is the advantage of using attribute binding sintax in simple urls

Answer (score 1):

Personally i try to use the same semantics for readability. Since i'm using [routerLink] at least once, i'll keep using it rather than routerLink, but both work obviousky ;)

Answer (score 1):

For simple urls, no need to use `[routerLink]`. But if the url is more complicated, I think `[routerLink]` is better. For example, you can use `[routerLink]="['/user', 'bob', 5, ...]"` instead of concatenate in normal way.