# Angular 2 modify router prams not getting added to URL

Tags: angular

If url contains `?edit=` `"true"` or`false`, I need to append that value to my router link.

Based on the below feedback I've modified my code.

But i'm this error `?edit=%5Bobject%20Object%5D` . value of the edit is not getting appended to the URL.

Please tell me what i'm doing wrong here.

```js
urlValue: any;
ngOnInit() {
  this.urlValue = {
    edit: this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.map((params) => params.get('edit'))
  };
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a class="production_model_col" [routerLink]="['/flow/PFSession']" [queryParams]="urlValue"><span >View Production Plan</span></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass query parameters with a routerLink in the new Router V 3 alpha (vladivostok)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880876/how-to-pass-query-parameters-with-a-routerlink-in-the-new-router-v-3-alpha-vlad)

Comment: Why are you accessing to the url through the window property? Do it the angular way...

Comment: I've updated my code. But i'm getting error `?edit=%5Bobject%20Object%5D`

Answer (score 0):

Use `queryParamMap`  from [Activated route](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route) as per [query parameters documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments) as below :

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';

constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  const value = this.route.queryParamMap.map(params => params.get('edit') || false ) ;
  this.urlValue = {
    edit: value
  };
}
```

and use it as below

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user/bob']" [queryParams]="urlValue">View Production Plan </a>
```

Comment: I'm getthing this error `?edit=%5Bobject%20Object%5D`. Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong here

Comment: You can check value of `this.route.queryParamMap.map((params) => params.get('edit')))` to `true` or `false` before assigning it to `this.urlValue`

Comment: Sorry, How do i do it ? i'm new to this Angular

Comment: Still only `object` is getting added to the url

Comment: you need to access the queryParams through this.route.snapshot