# Fragment specification for the RouterLink directive?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router

The Angular Router documentation mentions that we can use fragment parameters with the `RouterLink` directive, but how do we do this?  For example:

```
 <a routerLink="/crisis-center" [fragment]="ufoinvasion">
```

And then specify a crises with a `ufoinvasion` id in the crisis center?

Comment: Have you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880876/how-to-pass-query-parameters-with-a-routerlink-in-the-new-router-v-3-alpha-vlad ?

Comment: Fragements and query parameters are two different concepts IIUC ...?

Comment: Read the validated answer, it includes an example with fragments

Comment: OK I see the fragment syntax now.  Lets assume that the example navigates to `heroes`, and the fragment points to `yyy` which is the ID of the element containing a hero, will the specification of the fragment identifier now cause Angular to scroll the browser to the hero location.  In other words the URL ends up being /heros#yyy ...?

Comment: I assume that the code `fragment: 'anchor'` indicates it will be an anchor like #yyy as you said. In the Angular example it also adds the tag `<a id="anchor"></a>`