# Query Params Not Works Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have the following Html component:

```
<a [routerLink]="['experts']" [queryParams]="{profession:handyman}" class="category">
            <img src="../../assets/metal-saw.svg" width="60" height="60">
            <span>HandyMan</span>
        </a>
```

The problem is that when I click on the link, the experts route takes me, but without the `queryparams`. That is, `queryparams` does not seem to work but `routerLink` if it does.
I am using angular in its version 5. Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
<a [routerLink]="['/experts']" [queryParams]="{ profession: 'handyman'}" class="category">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import {Router,NavigationExtras} from '@angular/router';

 //

constructor(private router: Router) {}

public navigate(): void {
      let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
          queryParams: {'profession':handyman}
    };

    this.router.navigate(['/experts'], navigationExtras);
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<a (click)="navigate()" class="category">
            <img src="../../assets/metal-saw.svg" width="60" height="60">
            <span>HandyMan</span>
        </a>
```

And go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880876/how-to-pass-query-parameters-with-a-routerlink-in-the-new-router-v-3-alpha-vlad) answer for more details. And follow the official doc for [Angular routing](https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments).