# How can I pass data on button click from one component to another in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

HTML:

```
 <button [routerLink]="['/Request']">Request</button>
```

I am getting data in this component as product.name, product.id etc.

/Request is another view and I need to redirect user to that view on button click (Right now I am achieving this via [routerLink]) and to pass the value product.id to that view, as I want to use the value on that view.

Data:

My data is in the form of list, where on each button click, there would be different ID.

I am unable to pass the value to another view, on button click. What's the best approach?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880876/how-to-pass-query-parameters-with-a-routerlink-in-the-new-router-v-3-alpha-vlad

Comment: @WenHaoWu Using query params won't be secure. I know about it already. That's why I asked for best approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the value via URL. To this end, first, you need to declare it in your routing file. For example:

```
{
  path: 'request/:clientId
  component: RequestComponent
}
```

After that, just add it to your route. You can do:

```
<button [routerLink]=['/request', client.id]">Request</button>
```

or

```
<button routerLink="/request/{{ client.id }}">Request</button>
```

Comment: Will it be safe to use it? Exposing IDs to URL?

Comment: Is there any way to hide it?

Comment: Regarding to be safe or not, it depends on your application and what you're transmiting. As far as I know, the another option you have is using @Input/@Output (father-child relationship) or creating a service specific to do that.