# why router link not work although I use same link to component as href and it work?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-material, angular-components, angular7-router

I work on angular 7 app my issue is  routing not working when use routerLink
but it work when use href .

I make href link have parameter value report id

```
<a href="/pages/report/reportdetails?id={{subrep.reportID}}">
```

result working routing

```
http://localhost:4200/pages/report/reportdetails?id=3
```

when use router link in same place of href i do as below :

```
<a [routerLink]="['/pages/report/reportdetails/id=,subrep.reportID']">
```

result not working routing as url generated below

```
http://localhost:4200/pages/report/reportdetails/id%3D,subrep.reportID
```

app routing module :

```
{path:'report',component:ReportcategoryComponent,children:[
      {path:'reportdetails',component:ReportdetailsComponent},
      {path:'reportdetails/:id',component:ReportdetailsComponent},
      ]},
```

How to solve issue ?

I need router link make routing exactly same as href ?

**Result of first thread as below :**

result code you do for routing is

```
localhost:4200/pages/report/reportdetails/3
```

but i need it as

```
localhost:4200/pages/report/reportdetails?id=3
```

so what i change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passing the property `subrep.reportID` as a string , that why it navigate to the result you see. Try this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/pages/report/reportdetails', subrep.reportID ]">
```

If you want to add `id` as a query params, the syntax for it is `[queryParams]="{queryparam: value}"`:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/pages/report/reportdetails']" [queryParams]="{id: subrep.reportID}" >
```

You can read more about [RouterLink APIs here](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink)

Comment: result code you do for routing is http://localhost:4200/pages/report/reportdetails/3 but i need it as http://localhost:4200/pages/report/reportdetails?id=3 so what i change

Comment: @aboelham That is called as `queryParams`. This is how you pass query params [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37880877/11719787)

Comment: @aboelham like sameer Khan mentioned, it called query params , I updated my answer with it

Comment: @abo elham glad it help, please mark the answer as resolved if it did. Thank you