# route.queryParams.subscribe returns undefined in Angular Typescript Component

Tags: angular, typescript, url-routing, angular2-routing

I need to pass id as parameter to my angular component

In my html i have something like this

```
<a [routerLink]="['/viewjobdetail',  currentJob.id]">
    {{ currentJob.title }}
</a>
```

**app.module.ts** RouterModule.forRoot configured as

```
  { path: 'viewjobdetail/:id', component: JobDetailComponent }
```

in my calling component i have

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  debugger;
  var a = params['id'];
  this.displayJobId = parseInt(params['id']);
});
```

But when i check it its always showing **undefined** for a, what i am doing wrong here?
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. to achieve thiswe need to use query parameters with **queryParams**. I modified my html as below

```
<a [routerLink]="['/viewjobdetail']" [queryParams]="{id: currentJob.id}">
{{ currentJob.title }}
</a>
```

and in app.module.ts

```
{ path: 'viewjobdetail', component: JobDetailComponent }
```

and then in my calling component

```
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  
  var a = params.id;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `params` or `paramMap` instead of `queryParams`, query params can only recognise query params passed like `viewjobdetail?id=23`

`queryParams` is better since `params` may be deprecated in future releases

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
  debugger;
  var a = paramMap.get('id');
  this.displayJobId = parseInt(a);
});
```

Comment: So if i am going with queryParams, how should i declare it in my html a tag?

Comment: @NithinPaul If you want to use queryParams in your HTML, use it as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880876/how-to-pass-query-parameters-with-a-routerlink)

Comment: Just updated the code in my answer i mistakenly used the queryParams instead of paramMap, In additional to Ruben comment, if you used paramMap you don't need to change anything in the html