# How can I use routerLink with params?

Tags: angular

routerLink with params is not working

```
<a routerLink="/post?id=1">
  Link
</a>
```

I want to navigate in other links with params using routerLink

Answer (score 0):

Use  `[queryParams]` in adition to `routerLink` as explained in this post [How to pass query parameters with a routerLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880876/how-to-pass-query-parameters-with-a-routerlink)

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
<a [routerLink]="['/post']" [queryParams]="{ id: 1 }">View post</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your particular example you'd do the following routerLink:

```
    <a [routerLink]="['/post']" [queryParams]="{id: '1'}" queryParamsHandling="preserve"> Link
</a>
```

id can be variable as well.