# How to add a interpolation without escaping URL encoding in Angular 17?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to add a routeLink with full URL value defined in a string using Angular interpolation but when the page is executed it escape the URL.

Expected: `http://localhost:4200/books?page=3&sort=title` 
Returned: `http://localhost:4200/books%3Fpage%3D3&sort%3Dtitle`

```
<li *ngFor="let pageUrl of pageUrls" class="page-item">
  <a class="page-link" routerLink="{{ pageUrl.url }}">{{ pageUrl.index }}</a>
</li>
```

I know the escape is important for passing values correctly but is there any pipe or solution for this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is easy with Angular API:

1. https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink
2. [How to pass query parameters with a routerLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880876/how-to-pass-query-parameters-with-a-routerlink)

```html
<a class="page-link" 
  routerLink="/books" 
  [queryParams]="pageUrl.urlQueryParams">
  {{ pageUrl.index }}
</a>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It works! `<a class="page-link" routerLink="/books" [queryParams]="pageUrl.urlQueryParams">{{ pageUrl.index }}</a>`