# C# Mvc Support for QueryString Matrix Notation

Tags: c#, angular

I am using angular2 as the front end to a C# .NET stack.

The issue I am having is that the angular2 router uses matrix notation. (foo.com;a=b instead of foo.com?a=b).

I have been unable to figure out how to disable matrix notation in angular2, but I have been able to successfully map most urls through MVC into the angular2 app.

I am still having problems with urls such as "foo.com;search=abc.*"

Before I try messing around with the static file handler I was hoping that someone would know the answer to one of the following:

1. How to setup C#/Mvc to use querystring matrix notation
2. How to tell angular2 to stop using matrix notation.

So far searching the web/this site hasn't led me to any solutions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

---

Edit:

I'm using "@angular/router": "~3.1.0".  In beta releases there was support for ? on the main route and matrix was only used for child routes.  With the new router I can't find any support for traditional querystrings.

Answer (score 0):

It likely depends on which version of the router you are using.

See: [How to use the Querystring instead of ';'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631932/angular2-routing-how-to-use-the-querystring-instead-of)

See: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7616